# How to detect Kendo Grid MVC initial binding on controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyVm>().Name("grid").Columns(columns =>
  ...
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
        .Read(read => read.Action("List", "MyController", new { id = Model.Id }).Type(HttpVerbs.Get)))
```

On my controller I have :

```
public JsonResult List([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int id)
{ 
     //if (FIRST/INITIAL LOADING) ?????
     ...
}
```

How can I check on controller if its the initial loading/binding?

Thanks

Comment: you can store a session["Loaded"] and once you execute this action, you will set session["Loaded"]=true; and each time you check if session["Loaded"] ==null => you do the code you want to execute on first loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Data method to your read call which will use a js function that will return a global variable that's set true onLoad and sets it false.
Then every time you read data it will send IsFirstRead parameter

```
.Read(read => read.Action("List", "MyController", new { id = Model.Id }).Type(HttpVerbs.Get)).Data("isFirstRead"))

function isFirstRead() {
    if (firstTime) {
        firstTime = false;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

public JsonResult List([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int id, bool isFirstTime)
{ 
     //if (isFirstTime) ?????
     ...
}
```

GoodLuck